# Finding the closest number of array to another given number

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this program to write that I have a array of 11 numbers entered from me. Then I need to find the avarage sum of those numbers, and then im asked to find the closest number of this array to the avarage sum, and then the most distant element of the array to the avarage sum again. SO far I manage to write a program to create this array and find the avarage sum. I asssume there is something to do with abs function of cmath libary , but so far I only fail to make it.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {


unsigned const int size = 11;
float number[size];

for (unsigned i = 0; i<size; i++) {
    cout << "Please enter value for number  "
        << i + 1 << ":";
    cin >> number[i];
}
for (unsigned i = 0; i<size; i++) {
    cout << "Number " << i + 1 << " is : "
        << number[i] << endl;
}
unsigned int sum = 0;
for (unsigned i = 0; i<size; i++) {
    sum += number[i];
}
```

Comment: Iterate through the array and compare the difference between the average and the current number. Keep track of the largest and smallest distances so far, and the elements associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? You are not asking a question, just making a statement... It does seem that you have not posted the whole code..

In c++ usually to use "abs" you should use fabs from the "math.h" library!

Answer (score 0):

You will be okay with the compare operators. 
Just traverse your array in a loop and calculate the difference between your compare value and the current value on your array. Initiate a temporary variable that keeps the array entry that created the smallest difference.

Every time a difference that is smaller than the current one comes up replace the value in your temporary variable.

So you replace under the following condition: `If |number[i] - average_value| < |tmp_closest_val -average_val| Then tmp_closest_val = number[i] EndIf`.

I hope you get the concept from that rough draft.